# Formatting Categorical Variables for a linear regression

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am trying to build a linear regression model in R.  I am working on converting a categorical variable in to numeric for consumption by the model.  I want to convert the name of a procedure to a number and have the following line of code to do so.  It appears to be working successfully. I am using a library called CAR as well.

```
res$Procedure <- recode(res$Procedure, "'Primary Knee'='1'; 'Primary Hip'='2'; 'Revision Knee'='3'; 'Revision Knee'='4'; 
                          'Partial Knee'='5'; 'Revision Hip'='6'; 'Partial knee'='7'; 'Bilateral Hip'='8'; 
                          'Bilateral knee'='9'; 'Bilateral Knee'='9'; 'Resurfacing Hip'='10';'Resurfacing Hip '='10'; 'Revision knee'='3'")
```

I am then running the model -

```
lg1 = glm(BloodTransfusions~ Age+Hospital+Procedure+LenthOfStay,
      family=binomial(link=probit), data=res)
```

Then I am looking at the results of my model and this is were things look a little odd.

```
summary(lg1)
```

---

### | Variable |  P-Values  |

### |   Age    |            |

### |Hospital  |             |

### |Procedure1  |           |

### |Procedure2 |             |

### |Procedure3  |             |

Basically the model is treating each of the categorical variables that I converted as numbers as a distinct variable rather than a continuous one.  Does anyone have any suggestions? Or am I going about this the wrong way.  I appreciate the help!

Comment: In my opinion, you can not recode your categories into numerical values.  For example, if age equals 20 or 23, it makes sense.  However, if 'Primary Knee'='1' and 'Primary Hip'='2', what does procedure = 1.5 mean?

Comment: If you want to fit a linear regression model with categories, I think you need dummy variables to do the job.

Comment: I noticed in your recode data you have an in consistency `'Revision Knee'='3'; 'Revision Knee'='4';` (i.e. Revision Knee is 3 and 4). Perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: Is that `recode` from `dplyr` package? Are you sure your code works? You can use it like this `library(dplyr);
x = c("A","B","A");
recode(x, A=1, B=2)` to get a numeric variable as output.

Answer (score 0):

You can [dummify your dataframe](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dummy/dummy.pdf). This will create a binary variable out of every level of categorical variables.

```
library("dummy")
res.dummy <- dummy(res)
```

Then use `res.dummy` in glm.